# Access (JUnit) Localstack logs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, localstack

I am implementing an AWS Lambda with Java for my service and using Localstack to mock AWS services for my tests, e.g.

```java
@RunWith(LocalstackDockerTestRunner.class)
@LocalstackDockerProperties(services = {"dynamodb","lambda","s3","apigateway"})
public class AddIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        String[] argv = new String[]{"-g", "com/mydomain/services/myservice/integration/add", "./src/test/resources"
                + "/add.feature"};
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(argv, contextClassLoader);
    }
}
```

I am able to deploy Localstack and to upload the lambda successfully. My problem is when I perform the HTTP request to API Gateway to invoke the lambda, I get a `500 - internal server error` response, which indicates that something went wrong with the lambda execution. What makes this difficult to address is the absence of logging, i.e. I am unable to see anything about the lambda execution.

Therefore my question is how can I monitor such execution? For example, is there a way to have Localstack print or redirect logs? Any advice is welcome.

Thank you for your help